# How to request C++11 or later on a CMake-target?

Tags: c++, cmake

(This question is really about the "or later"-part.)

I'm a aware of the other answers which are telling us out to activate C++11 on a target/project in cmake.

**My question is really how do we express C++11 or later.**

As of CMake 3.8 we have the `cxx_std_11`-feature which forces C++11 on compilers (`-std=c++11`) which even support later standards and may even default to C++14 (gcc-7) or even 17 (gcc-8, iiuc).

There is also the CXX_STANDARD-target-property, but this is not transitive and also force the exact standard and not the "or later"-option.

The only way I found until now is to require `cxx_range_for` (or a similar feature) which makes CMake keep the default C++-standard of the compiler if at least C++11 is supported. This is supported as of CMake 3.1.

What is the correct way to select C++11 or later of a CMake-target?

Comment: It is not a good idea to build different parts of the project using different standards.

Comment: If your source code is C++11, why would you want to compile it with a later standard? Note that newer standards are not 100% backwards-compatible.

Comment: For a header-only-library you maybe don't want to force dependents to use C++11 if it also works with later versions. That's my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to ask for a *range* of standards in CMake.

Then only way (that I have used in the past) is to use e.g. [`check_cxx_compiler_flag`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckCXXCompilerFlag.html) to check for `-std=c++20`, `-std=c++17`, `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++11` (in that order) and use the highest with e.g. [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html).

If none of the flags listed is supported, then error out.

Comment: Good idea, but this not platform-agnostic.

Comment: @PatrickB. Unfortunately not. This works for two of the big three compilers (GCC and Clang), and you could add a check for MSVC to check its specific flags and options for standard in a similar way.

Comment: This should also work for all MSVC versions since 2015 Update 3 as Microsoft added support for these commandline switches in the compiler back then.

Answer (score 0):

As @Some programmer dude pointed out, only way to do so is to check for C++17, then C++14 then C++11. Looking into CMake sources itself gives interesting idea how to do it in platform-agnostic way. In here [`try_compile` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_compile.html#id3) is used with corresponding CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD passed, so CMake itself determines which compiler flag should be used. Thus to check for C++14:

```
try_compile(CMake_CXX14_WORKS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cm_cxx14_check.cpp
  CMAKE_FLAGS -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=14
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT
  )
```

where cm_cxx14_check.cpp is dummy file with `main`.

This is key idea here, although full logic also checks if `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` wasn't already defined or if CMake knows `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17` (CMake >= 3.8). Also, CMake checks for newest standard only for GNU or Clang, but I believe it is because it is not needed in MSVC in non-library code. MSVC has always enabled the newest standard by default.

Unfortunately, here is some also a corner case with GNU 4.8: ["The GNU 4.8 standard library's cstdio header is not aware that C++14 honors C11's removal of "gets" from stdio.h and results in an error"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/3307e10fc4ef5ffb551df35bc0978a2543305e9d)